# PHP unable to upload emails attachments to ftp server

Tags: php, ftp, imap, email-attachments

I have been trying to upload to an FTP server the attachments I am getting from an IMAP email, here is my code:

## To retrieve attachments

```
<?php
    /* 
        attachedFile() returns the attachment already decoded.
        For this example the encode type was base64, so it used imap_base64 to decode 
    */
    function attachedFile($uid, $section, $encoding) {
        # Returns file as an encoded string
        $file = imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $uid, $section, FT_UID); 

        switch ($encoding) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                $file = imap_8bit($file); break;
            case 2:
                $file = imap_binary($file); break;
            case 3:
                $file = imap_base64($file); break;
            case 4:
                $file = quoted_printable_decode($file); break;
        }
        $mime = imap_fetchmime($this->conn, $uid, $section, FT_UID);

        # returning decoding file, I use mime in another section
        return array('file' => $file, 'mime' => $mime);
    }

    /* 
        Returns file as stream using attached_file() returns
    */
    function streamedAttach( $filename, $uid, $section, $encoding ) {
        # Returns file as stream using attached_file() returns
        $attach = $this->attachedFile($uid, $section, $encoding);
        $attachment = $attach['file'];

        $stream = fopen($filename, 'w+');
        if ( $stream === false ) return false;

        $ok = fputs($stream, $attach['file']);

        # raw printing
        echo "Bytes: " . $ok . "<br />";

        if ($ok===false) return false;

        return $stream;
    }
?>
```

streamedAttach receives the return of attached_file and write into the 'handler' $stream.

Then it send that stream ATTENTION: I haven't close the stream, because when I was closing it... ftp_fput was failing. So I left it opened.

However if you see this line

```
echo "Bytes: " . $ok . "<br />";
```

It is writing bytes:

[BYTES written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVUPk.png)

## this is to upload to FTP

```
function login($user, $pass) {
    $ok = $this->conn!==false;
    if ($ok) {
        # Credentials
        $this->user = $user; 
        $this->pass = $pass;

        $login = @ftp_login($this->conn, $this->user, $this->pass);
        $pasv = ftp_pasv($this->conn, true);

        $ok = ($login && $pasv);
    }
    return $ok;
}

function uploadStreamedFile($stream, $destination) {
    $ok = $this->conn!==false;
    if ($ok) {
        $ok = ftp_fput($this->conn, $destination, $stream, FTP_BINARY);
        fclose($stream);
    }
    return $ok;
}
```

Now, upload_streamed_file receives $stream and using ftp_fput (because is a pointer) creates a file on the server... the bad thing is the file is 0 KB sized.

[files on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIzyh.png)

## this is where I call them

```
$ftp = new ftp_conn();
$ftp->basePath = "POS_ARCHIVE";

# This is the same name as in the email
$filename = "th.jpg"; 

# Sample data
$uid = 18; 
$section = 2; 
$encode = 3;
$path = "POS_ARCHIVE/4700327771/$filename";

echo $filename . "<br />";

if ($ftp->login(FTP_UID, FTP_PWD)) {

        # $mailbox I have the instance before.
        $streamed = $mailbox->streamedAttach($filename, $uid, $section, $encode);
        $ok = $ftp->uploadStreamedFile($streamed, $path);
        if ( $ok ) echo "There you go!";
        else echo "Nope, nope.";
} else 
    echo "Nope, nope.";
```

Can you help me, I've been 2 hours with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `streamed_attach()` returns, the file pointer for the stream is pointing to the end of the file. So when you try to upload it with `ftp_fput()`, it immediately reads EOF and uploads an empty file. You need to go back to the beginning of the file so you can read what you've written to the file.

```
function upload_streamed_file( $stream, $destination ) {
   if ( $this->conn === false ) {
       return false; //Later I'll add more details of why not.
   } else {
       //error( $destination );
       rewind($stream);
       $ok = ftp_fput( $this->conn, $destination, $stream, FTP_BINARY );
       fclose( $stream );
       return $ok;
   }
}
```

An alternative would be to close the stream in `streamed_attach()`, and then use `ftp_put` with the filename instead of `ftp_fput` with the stream.

Comment: IT WORKED! AS YOU SAID! I just wrote rewind( $stream ); and it worked! after fputs(); THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was already thinking about becoming a politician or something like that haha.